# Why don't check(), require() and assert() result in a smart cast?

Tags: kotlin

Consider the following code fragment:

```
object C {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(vararg args: String) {
        val s: String? = null
        check(s != null) {
            "The string is null"
        }
        require(s != null) {
            "The string is null"
        }
        assert(s != null) {
            "The string is null"
        }
        s.length
    }
}
```

While both `check()` and `require()` have

```
contract {
    returns() implies value
}
```

in their body, the above code still doesn't compile, forcing me to use either `?.`:

```
s?.length
```

or `!!`:

```
s!!.length
```

Why no smart cast is performed in the above code?

Comment: What Kotlin language version your project is  set up to use?

Comment: @RomanElizarov It's 1.2.70 (1.2 is set in the project settings as both the language and the API version).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I answered a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53139997/6296561) a while ago on the difference between `assert` and `require`. TL;DR: `assert`isn't guaranteed to throw an exception, but `require` is. In Kotlin 1.3, it also uses contracts, which means if the method returns, the compiler knows the statement is correct, and it can apply smart cast if applicable.

This explains why `assert` doesn't do it; returning from an assertion does **not** mean the statement is true. With the code you have, it would not throw an exception unless `ea` is true. Assert won't trigger smart cast, even with 1.3.

`check` and `require` both trigger smart cast on 1.3 and up (because of contracts), assert doesn't (no contracts and no guarantee it actually throws an exception if the condition fails).

I found [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/preconditions-should-activate-smart-cast-no/8091) post on the Kotlin forums, asking exactly what you are. The contracts were present for quite a long time, but [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-doesnt-smart-cast-use-data-from-in-code-contracts/6567) post also backs up my initial assumptions: While the contracts are present, **they weren't ready**. Effectively disabled, as the second post mentions. Which is why smart cast doesn't work.

However, in Kotlin 1.3, the contracts were released. If you upgrade, you'll see that it does work (at least it does for me).

---

Full contract support was added in [1.3-M2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/08/kotlin-1-3-m2/), which is a pre-release for 1.3.