# Kotlin checkNotNull vs requireNotNull

Tags: kotlin, nullable, nullability

As I learn new components in Kotlin, I came accross `requireNotNull` and `checkNotNull` but the only difference I've found is that `requireNotNull` can throw an `IllegalArgumentException` while `checkNotNull` can throw an `IllegalStateException`. Is this the only reason why there are two methods, or I'm missing some under-the-hood implementation detail?

Comment: It's like check and require... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53139676/829571

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a semantic difference and hence it throws different exceptions. RequireNotNull is used to check input values, typically at the beginning of a method, while checkNotNull is used anywhere to check the current state.

Answer (score 23):

The exception types are the only *practical* difference, as far as the compiler is concerned — but **there's a big difference in *intent***, for anyone reading the code:

• **`require…()` functions** are for checking parameters, to **confirm that a function's input fulfils its contract**. So you'd normally call them first thing in a function. (Of course, Kotlin's non-nullable types mean that you wouldn't need to call `requireNotNull()` for a single parameter; but you might need to check a more complex condition on a combination of parameters or their sub-objects.) That's why they throw `IllegalArgumentException`: it's checking that the arguments are legal.

• **`check…()` functions** are for checking the relevant properties, to **confirm that the object or whatever is in a valid state for this function to be called now**. (Again, any properties that were *never* null would be typed accordingly, so `checkNotNull()` is more appropriate for cases where a property, combination, and/or sub-property can be null, but this function mustn't be called when they are.) So they throw `IllegalStateException`: they're checking that the object's current state allows the function to be called.

In both cases, you could of course write a standard `if` check (as you would in Java). Or you could use the Elvis operator `?:` to do the check the first time the possibly-null value is used. But these functions give you an alternative that's in a more declarative form: you'd normally put them at the top of the function, where they spell out what the function's contract is, in a way that's obvious to anyone glancing at the code.

As a linked answer points out, there are also **`assert…()` functions**, which again have more of a semantic difference than a practical one. Those **are for detecting programming errors *away* from the boundary of a function call**: for confirming invariants and other conditions, and for all the checks in unit tests and other automated tests.

(Assertions have another important difference: they can be enabled and disabled from the command-line. Though in my experience, that's  not a very good thing. If a check is important, it should *always* be run: be mandatory; if not, then it should be removed, or at least moved to automated tests, once the code is debugged.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for differences in implementation, the best place to go would be the source code. In this case it seems like there are no differences aside from the different exception thrown, the source for both methods is otherwise identical.

`checkNotNull`

```
[...]
if (value == null) {
    val message = lazyMessage()
    throw IllegalStateException(message.toString())
} else {
    return value
}
```

`requireNotNull`

```
[...]
if (value == null) {
    val message = lazyMessage()
    throw IllegalArgumentException(message.toString())
} else {
    return value
}
```

Therefore the difference is purely semantic. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522300/10082297) from @gidds details some good scenarios for using them both.

Comment: _"I don't have a good reason as to why there are two methods"_ ... This was the question. As such, this does not answer the question and was already stated by the OP.

Comment: @StevenJeuris The question asked whether there was a difference *"under the hood"* which was the part I focused on answering. What I meant was that I didn't have a source which explained why two methods that threw different exceptions existed in the first place. Maybe I should have phrased it differently.

Comment: Understood. I guess this answer is indeed still relevant to answer the _"or I'm missing some under-the-hood implementation detail"_ part of this question. I'll gladly up vote after a clarifying edit (can't right now).